# Custom Tooltip for input text

Tags: html, css, tooltip

i am trying to implement a tooltip like div using css. 
i am refering

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip

above example shows a top tool tip.

can any one help me change this to bottom tool tip.  I am very weak in CSS and design.

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any attempts made so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go this could help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -40px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is...

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    
    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with some changes in CSS.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -215%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #555;
  border-width: 6px;
  margin-left: -6px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
  <h2>Tooltip</h2>
  <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

  <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
    <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...!!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    
    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">


<div class="tooltip">Hover Me
  <span class="tooltiptext">bottom tooltip</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```